# How to create a shortcut in xfce for "Run Program ..."

Tags: xfce, desktop-environment, xfce4-terminal, launcher

**OS**: Linux Mint 18.2 sonya
**DE**: XFCE

By clicking the menu-button in the panel, there exists the option `Run Program ...`. I want to create a shortcut in `Menu/Settings/Settings-Manager/Keyboard/Application-Shortcuts` to access this application-launcher from the menu. Does there a terminal command exist which i can use to assign a shortcut-key-combination in order to call this application-launcher?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the documentation from [the Xfce documentation page](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/getting-started), you can either use the `Run Program` from the `Start menu` or you can press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>.

> Application Finder
>   If you know the name of a program and it is not on the panel or in the desktop menu you can use the run dialog. To open the dialog **type Alt-F2** or choose the Run Program... option from the desktop menu.

**Note:**

This is **not** an `Xfce` only option.

**Edit**

Alternatively, you can start it from the command line using:

```
xfce4-appfinder --collapsed
```

This can be conveniently accessed via `Keyboard > Application Shortcuts` in the Settings menu by adding a keyboard shortcut of your choice.

Comment: After looking up the shortcut [Alt]+[F2] in the Application shortcuts, i found the according command `xfce4-appfinder --collapsed` i was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: In Xfce 4.14 I noticed that [ALT] + [F2] is equivalent to `xfce4-appfinder --collapsed` where [ALT] + [F3] is the same as running `xfce4-appfinder` (full view).